# What's going on with "Kurtlar Vadisi Pusu"?

Tags: support, spam-detection

We seem to be under some sort of mini spam attack... it's text from a foreign TV show or something, occasionally with links that I dare not follow.

See:

[Kurtlar Vadisi Pusu 181. Bölüm FULL izle 07 Şubat 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753000/kurtlar-vadisi-pusu-181-bolum-full-izle-07-subat-2013)

and

[Kurtlar Vadisi Pusu 181. Bolum Full izle 7 Şubat 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756322/kurtlar-vadisi-pusu-181-bolum-full-izle-7-ubat-2013)

This is the second or third time today I've seen these questions pop up.  In the first instance, a second sock puppet even commented on it.

Is there a way for moderators to block questions with the text `Kurtlar Vadisi Pusu` in it?  Other than flagging all attempts for moderator attention, is there anything broader that can be done?

Comment: this account will be banned to ask question ..due to getting huge downvote IMO .. so no worry .. just downvote and flag and close would be fine ..   mod deleted both account ...

Comment: @NullPointer - sure, but that's three seperate accounts. I see all three users have been nuked, but I imagine more will show up eventually.  I guess I'll just keep flagging :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have a blacklist, but things don't usually get to that point unless they're getting way out of hand (say, if the spam continues over several days or spans across numerous accounts).

In the meantime, just keep flagging. As you can tell, we can and will readily nuke spam accounts in a single click, so in the vast majority of cases it's not too much of a hassle for us.

Answer (score 0):

There(OP and there post ) are only need to be

[image]

<sub>[above image source](http://loyalkng.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/flamethrower.jpg)</sub>